# Web Crawler Text Cloud

Tags: python

I need help with a text cloud program I'm working on. I realize it's homework, but I've gotten pretty far on my own, only to now be stumped for hours. I'm stuck on the web crawler part. The program is supposed to open a page, gather all the words from that page, and sort them by frequency. Then it's supposed to open any links on that page and get the words on that page, etc. The depth is controlled by a global variable DEPTH. In the end, it's supposed to put all the words from all pages together to form a text cloud.

I'm trying to use recursion to call a function to keep opening links until the depth is reached. The import statement at the top is only to use a function called getHTML(URL), which returns a tuple of the list of words on the page, and any links on the page.

Here is my code so far. Every function works as it should, except for getRecursiveURLs(url, DEPTH) and makeWords(i). I'm also not 100% sure about the counter(List) function at the bottom.

```
from hmc_urllib import getHTML

MAXWORDS = 50
DEPTH = 2

all_links = []

def getURL():
    """Asks the user for a URL"""

    URL = input('Please enter a URL: ')

    #all_links.append(URL)

    return makeListOfWords(URL), getRecursiveURLs(URL, DEPTH)


def getRecursiveURLs(url, DEPTH):
    """Opens up all links and adds them to global all_links list,
    if they're not in all_links already"""

    s = getHTML(url)
    links = s[1]
    if DEPTH > 0:
        for i in links:
            getRecursiveURLs(i, DEPTH - 1)
            if i not in all_links:
                all_links.append(i)
                #print('This is all_links in the IF', all_links)
                makeWords(i)#getRecursiveURLs(i, DEPTH - 1)
            #elif i in all_links:

             #   print('This is all_links in the ELIF', all_links)
              #  makeWords(i) #getRecursiveURLs(i, DEPTH - 1)
    #print('All_links at the end', all_links)
    return all_links





def makeWords(i):
    """Take all_links and create a dictionary for each page.
    Then, create a final dictionary of all the words on all pages."""

    for i in all_links:
        FinalDict = makeListOfWords(i)
        #print(all_links)
        #makeListOfWords(i))
    return FinalDict


def makeListOfWords(URL):
    """Gets the text from a webpage and puts the words into a list"""

    text = getHTML(str(URL))
    L = text[0].split()
    return cleaner(L)


def cleaner(L):

    """Cleans the text of punctuation and removes words if they are in the stop list."""

    stopList = ['', 'a', 'i', 'the', 'and', 'an', 'in', 'with', 'for',
                'it', 'am', 'at', 'on', 'of', 'to', 'is', 'so', 'too',
                'my', 'but', 'are', 'very', 'here', 'even', 'from',
                'them', 'then', 'than', 'this', 'that', 'though']

    x = [dePunc(c) for c in L]

    for c in x:
        if c in stopList:
            x.remove(c)

    a = [stemmer(c) for c in x]

    return counter(a)


def dePunc( rawword ):
    """ de-punctuationifies the input string """

    L = [ c for c in rawword if 'A' <= c <= 'Z' or 'a' <= c <= 'z' ]
    word = ''.join(L)
    return word


def stemmer(word):

    """Stems the words"""

    # List of endings
    endings = ['ed', 'es', 's', 'ly', 'ing', 'er', 'ers']

    # This first case handles 3 letter suffixes WITH a doubled consonant. I.E. spammers -> spam
    if word[len(word)-3:len(word)] in endings and word[-4] == word[-5]:
        return word[0:len(word)-4]

    # This case handles 3 letter suffixes WITHOUT a doubled consonant. I.E. players -> play
    elif word[len(word)-3:len(word)] in endings and word[-4] != word[-5]:
        return word[0:len(word)-3]

    # This case handles 2 letter suffixes WITH a doubled consonant. I.E. spammed -> spam
    elif word[len(word)-2:len(word)] in endings and word[-3] == word[-4]:
        return word[0:len(word)-3]

    # This case handles 2 letter suffixes WITHOUT a doubled consonant. I.E. played -> played
    elif word[len(word)-2:len(word)] in endings and word[-3] != word[-4]:
        return word[0:len(word)-3]

    # If word not inflected, return as-is.
    else:
        return word

def counter(List):
    """Creates dictionary of words and their frequencies, 'sorts' them,
    and prints them from most least frequent"""

    freq = {}
    result = {}
 # Assign frequency to each word
    for item in List:
        freq[item] = freq.get(item,0) + 1

    # 'Sort' the dictionary by frequency
    for i in sorted(freq, key=freq.get, reverse=True):
        if len(result) < MAXWORDS:
            print(i, '(', freq[i], ')', sep='')
            result[i] = freq[i]
    return result
```

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials how to crawl a website, for example: http://ms4py.org/2010/4/10/python-search-engine-crawler-part-1/.

Comment: Are there limits to what you can use? I would recommend using queues and threading, rather than recursion, to crawl.

Comment: Also, what exactly is wrong with `getRecursiveURLS()`?

Comment: `def makeWords(i):` ... `for i in all_links:` You are passing i as a parameter but also assigning it in the for loop. Not necessarily the problem but I would consider changing it to `def makeWords():`

Comment: @ Joel, Right now the code returns the words from the pages multiple times instead of just one. I figure the problem is in either makeWords() or getRecursiveURLs() because everything else seems to work. Also I can't figure out how to assign all those words to one final dictionary.

Comment: @ ms4py, Thanks! I'll check it out. I've googled a lot but maybe just not the right keywords.

Comment: @ Jesse, thanks! I knew it was weird to pass it and assign it as well. But the two functions together are just stumping me.

Answer (score 2):

It is not totally clear the exact requirements for the assignment but from what I can gather you are looking to visit all pages up to the DEPTH once and only once. Also, you want to get all of the words off all of the pages and work with the aggregate result. The snippet below is what you are looking for however it is untested(I do not have hmc_urllib). `all_links`, `makeWords` and `makeListOfWords` have been removed but the rest of the code would be the same.

```
visited_links = []

def getURL():
    url = input('Please enter a URL: ')
    word_list = getRecursiveURLs(url, DEPTH)
    return cleaner(word_list) # this prints the word count for all pages

def getRecursiveURLs(url, DEPTH):
    text, links  = getHTML(url)
    visited_links.append(url)
    returned_word_list = text.split()
    #cleaner(text.split()) # this prints the word count for the current page

    if DEPTH > 0:
        for link in links:
            if link not in visited_links:
                returned_word_list += getRecursiveURLs(link, DEPTH - 1)
    return returned_word_list
```

Once you have a list of cleaned and stemmed words you can use the following functions to generate the word count dictionary and print the word count dictionary respectively:

```
def counter(words):
    """
    Example Input: ['spam', 'egg', 'egg', 'egg', 'spam', 'spam', 'egg', 'egg']
    Example Output: {'spam': 3, 'egg', 5}
    """
    return dict((word, x.count(word)) for word in set(words))

def print_count(word_count, word_max):
    """
    Example Input: {'spam': 3, 'egg', 5}
    Prints the word list up to the word_max sorted by frequency
    """
    for word in sorted(word_count, key=word_count.get, reverse=True)[:word_max]:
        print(word,'(', word_count[word], ')', sep= '')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The code you gave me prints out each word and its frequency per page correctly, but the dictionary that is created is only of the entire text per page. I need the final dictionary to have the individual words from all of the pages as keys and their frequency as values. This would let me sort them the way I need to. Right now, it returns something like this: spam(8) page(1) love(1). That's the first page. The next page goes: stem(4) page(2) these(2), and so on. The final result needs to be spam(8) stem(4) page(3) these(2) love(1)

Comment: I am not sure why it is not working for you. Once you get to `return cleaner(global_word_list)` the `global_word_list` should have all the words from all the pages in it. I have read your code as posted several times and there is no obvious reason for the behavior you indicated. Have you made any modifications to cleaner or counter?

Also, you shouldn't use List as the parameter name for counter. List is a Python Keyword and it can cause unexpected behavior if it is used in other ways.

Comment: Sorry for all the confusing comments. I found the problem. First off, the line global_word_list += text.split() returns an error. It says local variable referenced before assignment. So I changed it to global_word_list.append(text.split()). The problem with split is that it creates a list. So when it's time to create the dictionary, it sees a list of lists, which are each page's text. I need to figure out how to make it just one list.

Comment: I just saw your last comment. `global_word_list += text.split()` should work correctly. The error sounds like `global_word_list` was undefined. Make sure that `global_word_list = []` is top level and comes before `def getRecursiveURL` . If it still gives you problems let me know, I can refactor `getRecursiveURL to bubble up the word list rather than use a global variable.

Comment: I had it before any of the functions, and it still gave me an error saying it was undefined.

Comment: I have update the version to bubble up the word list rather than use a global. I am unable to test it locally without hmc_urllib and your test data but I have used this technique many times successfully.